# css link appear only while hovering the image

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to make the f1 link appearing on image only on hovering the image. i tried this but this is not working , link is not appearing .
can someone explain the problem and type a working code?

```
<div class="caine1">
      <img src="1.png" width="400" height="250"></img>
      <a href="#" id="f1">Female</a>
       </div>

   

    #f1 {
    position:absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 200;
}


.caine1 img:hover #f1 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `+`.

```css
#f1 {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 200;
}

/* You missed a + here */
.caine1 img:hover + #f1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="caine1">
  <img src="1.png" width="400" height="250" /> <!--Also, images don't have closing tags - they're self closing like <br/>-->
  <a href="#" id="f1">Female</a>
</div>
```